# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Moya"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My new project using swift 4.2 has below **podFile**:

```
pod 'Moya', '12.0.1'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '4.0'
pod 'Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper'
```

Intalling using **pod install --verbose** shows error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Moya":
>         In Podfile:
>           Moya (= 12.0.1)
>
> ```
>     Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
>       Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper/Core (= 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
>         Moya (~> 6.0.0)
>
> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SwiftyJSON":
>   In Podfile:
>     Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
>       Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper/Core (= 1.0.3) was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
>         SwiftyJSON (~> 2.3.2)
>
>     SwiftyJSON (= 4.0)
> ```

Comment: Your specified versions are not compatible with each other, drop them and see what versions would be autoresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your pod version are not compatible with each other, this `Podfile` won't work.

But you can fix it.

But you have to check what podspecs of your pods to do this:

[Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper](https://github.com/AvdLee/Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper/blob/010e843b6ff292c6dde5ebbf51fd36cfcce2e216/Moya-SwiftyJSONMapper.podspec): latest version of this pod is `"3.0.0"`, and it depends on `Moya`, version `10.x` and any version of `SwiftyJSON`.

So your version `4.0` of `SwiftyJSON` will be ok.

But you've specified that you want to install `Moya` version `12.0.1`, which is not one of the `10.x` version, so it is incompatible.

So you have to get rid of version `12.0.1` requirement, to make it all work.

```
pod 'Moya', '~> 10.0'
```

or just

```
pod 'Moya'
```

---

And, I think it's better to have Podfile with no version specified before first `pod install`. And only after auto-resolved combination of pods is installed you should freeze version requirements.