# How to use same pods for iOS and tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, tvos

I want to use same pod for iOS and tvOS. For that i have write code in pod file like this,

```
def shared_pods
    pod 'Moya', '~> 9.0' #Alamofire wrapper
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.4.5'

end

target 'iosApp' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!
  inhibit_all_warnings!
  shared_pods

end

target 'TVApp' do
    platform :tvos, '9.0'
    use_frameworks!
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    shared_pods
end
```

But i get the error `The platform of the target TVApp (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with Stripe, which does not support tvOS.`

Other pods like, 
 `pod 'DynamicCodable'
  pod 'Stripe', '~> 15.0.1'
  pod 'GooglePlacesSearchController'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'NTMonthYearPicker'
  pod 'NYTPhotoViewer', '~> 1.1.0'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
  pod 'SendBirdSDK', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper'
  #tappable label
  pod 'ActiveLabel'
  #calendar
  pod 'FSCalendar'
  #Location
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'CreditCardValidator'
  pod 'FittedSheets'
  pod 'Branch'
  pod 'CarbonKit'
  pod 'AWSS3'` also not compatible with tvOS, but i want to use those in tvOS.

How can i use same framework for both OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Moya"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647891/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-moya)

Comment: No, It is not same question. I want library for tvOS.

Answer (score 2):

The Moya pod is compatible with tvOS, as you can see in its [.podspec file](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Moya.podspec):

```
  s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'
```

I tried running a project with your .podspec configuration, and had some problems with an outdated `Moya` sub dependency `"Result", "~> 3.0"`. However, on the last release, this dependency has been updated to `"Result", "~> 4.1"`, and I was able to run Moya on iOS 9.0 tvOS successfully.

Try using the most recent release:

```
def shared_pods
    pod 'Moya', '13.0.1' #Alamofire wrapper
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.4.5'
end
```

Edit

However, as you mentioned in your edit, all your another pod dependencies are incompatible with tvOS:

```
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `DynamicCodable (1.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `Stripe (15.0.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `GooglePlacesSearchController (0.2.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.41.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `NTMonthYearPicker (1.0.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `FLAnimatedImage (1.0.12)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `NYTPhotoViewer (1.1.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `MGSwipeTableCell (1.6.9)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `SendBirdSDK (3.0.154)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `RSKImageCropper (2.2.3)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `ActiveLabel (1.0.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `FSCalendar (2.8.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `GooglePlaces (3.5.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `CreditCardValidator (0.4)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `FittedSheets (1.4.5)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `Branch (0.29.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `CarbonKit (2.3.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
[!] The platform of the target `tvApp` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `AWSS3 (2.12.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.
```

To check the compatibility, you can open the pod repository and check the `.podspec` file. For example, the [Stripe .podspec](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Stripe.podspec) doesn't have a `tvos.deployment_target`.

You can't use frameworks that are incompatible with a project target.

Comment: The question clearly showed that the author had issue with running `Stripe` and other uncompatible pods with `tvOS`, and not any specific version of a pod on `tvOS`, which makes your answer about a specific pod `Moya` a bit out of track.

Comment: @denis_lor No, the title of the question implied that but the content of the question showed that the issue was a specific pod.  So this answer is good.

Comment: Might be, we need the author to put more details

Comment: I started answering before the edit, then OP changed `Moya` to `Stripe` and added other incompatible pods. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From `Stripe` documentation https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios it says:

> The library is compatible with `iOS` 9.0 and up

That's why it doesn't work for your `tvos` platform target.

Comment: So was your question about using some libraries such as `Stripe` as well in your `tvOS` platform target? I thought your question was about that since I saw you included the error about `Stripe` specifically. I understand you might want to use in your `tvOS` platform target as well other pods that you listed, but specifically the one you got the error, `Stripe`, is not compatible with `tvOS`. For the others, you just have to go to their website/cocoapods link/github page and look if they support it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is quite clear? "The platform of the target TVApp (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with Stripe, which does not support tvOS." Stripe doesn't seem to run on tvOS, which means you can't use it.